# inserting to ms sql database not null

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a form that adds information of employee, but i want all the fields to be filled up. I don't know if this is the right code but even if I don't check the radio buttons and check boxes still adds the values on my database from the textboxes. I will appreciate all types of response. Thank you in advance.

```
if  (((textBox2.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox3.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox4.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox5.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox6.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox7.Text == string.Empty ||
            textBox8.Text == string.Empty) &&
            (radioButton1.Checked == true ||
            radioButton2.Checked == true) &&
            (checkBox1.Checked == true ||
            checkBox2.Checked == true)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Open();
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            string save = "INSERT INTO emp (empID, empLName, empFName, empAge, empGender, empAddress, empEmail, empUser, empPass, empType)  values('"
                + eid + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + age + "','" + gender + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','"
                + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + postn + "')";

            SqlCommand cmdsave = new SqlCommand(save, connect);
            cmdsave.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
            connect.Close();

            Admin adm = new Admin();
            adm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You should use parameters here

Comment: Make sure all parameters are correctly passed based on datatype vice

Comment: there is the way for you do that, if u have a `<div id="ParentControls" runat="server">   
<contro A/> <contro B/> <contro C/> 
</div>` so could use foreach in that ParentControls like this `foreach 
(Control c in ParentControls)
    { 
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
if(c.Text ==  string.Empty)
            return true;
        }
    } return false;`
u could write a function to pass a Control (parent)  and return true if any textbox is emty. with checkbox write in other conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IF condition should be like this

```
if  ((textBox2.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox3.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox4.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox5.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox6.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox7.Text == string.Empty ||
        textBox8.Text == string.Empty ||
        (radioButton1.Checked == false &&
        radioButton2.Checked == false ) ||
        !checkBox1.Checked ||
        !checkBox2.Checked ))
```

OR

You can use FOREACH

```
bool invalid = false;
foreach(Control ctr in this.Controls)
{
  if(ctr is TextBox)
  {
    if(ctr.Text == string.empty)
      {
        invalid = true;
        break;
      }
  }
}

if(invalid)
{
  MessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```